# Exception when referencing MapView in a fragment - OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have written an app with OSMdroid using activities, but I am now trying to port it over to fragments instead (I'm new to fragments though). I am getting the error: 
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.osmdroid.views.MapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)' on a null object reference"

It seems that the MapView has not yet been initialised, am I initialising in the wrong place (OnCreateView)? According to the activity lifecycle, OnCreate is called before OnCreateView, so it would make sense that it is not recognised, but I am confused as to where then to put my code.

Code for my implementation of the fragment:

```
 //inflating fragment layout
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        map = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));

        setupMap();
    }

//initializing map
    private void setupMap() {
        //adding zoom and touch controls
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        //getting current location using coarse/fine location so we can set centerpoint
        currentLocation = getCurrentLocation();

... code continues ...
```

Error stack trace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.osmdroid.views.MapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at skicompanion.skicompanion.MapFragment.setupMap(MapFragment.java:101)
                                                                               at skicompanion.skicompanion.MapFragment.onCreate(MapFragment.java:86)
                                                                               at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2214)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153)
                                                                               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:800)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:487)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add the stacktrace. It is also dangerous to call getActivity within the OnCreate methos. At this point the fragment might not be attached to the activity. What then lead to an getActivity() = null. Better do this within in  onActivityCreated().

Comment: Sure, I just added it above. So should I add all my map implementation, instead to onActivityCreated()? This would make sense, as it is after onCreate in the lifecycle

Comment: Initialize view elements in the onCreateView and context based calls in onActivityCreated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted code it doesn't look like you need to override onCreate method in your case. just move this code:

```
    context = getActivity();
    Configuration.getInstance().load(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));

    setupMap();
```

into the onCreateView method before the return call and should be ok.

Comment: Thank you donfuxx, it worked - it seems I need to learn more about fragments to understand why..
The MapView grid is there with the overlays, even showing my current location. however the map itself is not showing its just a grid. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe the internet is just slow ;-) ...or the location was somewhere in the nowhere, try zooming out of the map. Also for locating the current location you need to add some permissions in the manifest